# How to insert a line break in a StringVar in Crystal Reports

Tags: string, crystal-reports, escaping

How do I enter a line break (or other non-text characters usually solved with escape characters) in a StringVar in Crystal Reports?

Wanted output:

> line 1
>   line 2

I've tried `StringVar s := "line 1 \n line 2";`, but that does not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may not be much of an improvement, but you could build a string-formatting, custom function:

```
// sf()
Function (Stringvar text)

    Stringvar Array keys := ["\n"];
    Stringvar Array values := [Chr(10)+Chr(13)];

    Numbervar i;

    For i := 1 to Ubound(keys) do (
        text := Replace(text, keys[i], values[i])
    );

    text;

//{@ text}
sf("line 1 \n line 2")
```

This would offer you some extensibility should you need to support additional escape sequences.

Comment: Overkill for my task, but a nice general and flexible solution.

Answer (score 12):

i have simply used following code for line break

"This formula field " + ChrW(13) + " contains a line break!"

Answer (score 4):

I've found a functional, albeit not code aesthetical, solution:

```
StringVar s := "line 1" + chr(10) + chr(13) + "line 2";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it from the database itself with `char(13)` in SQL Server Management Studio    15.0.18390.0.
Example: `SELECT I.Name + char(13) + I.Name DISCRPIPTION from Items I`. 
Result in Crystal Report:-

[image]