# The text we need to print includes words like "AND" "OR" "IF" that crystal is picking up as code

Tags: crystal-reports

I am making a custom report, really not complicated at all. Only using one table/ Basically, the report needs to print a list of text if the customer group is the same as the parameter “Builder”. I need to write a formula to say

```
IF {?Builder}=”123456”
THEN
“QTXE FANS 6”  DUCT FOR ALL BATHROOMS WITH TUB OR SHOWER 
QTRE FANS 4” DUCT ½ BATH OR ONLY ROOM AND THE LAUNDRY AS LONG AS IT IS NOT THE WHOLE     HOUSE FAN 
PULL WIRE FROM WHOLE HOUSE FAN SWITCH TO FURNACE 
TERMINALS 4 & 6 on relay
IF BIG CUSTOM VERIFY IF HOOD FAN NEEDS PULLED TO FURNACE 
LOW VOLT PANEL WITH # 10 GROUND PULLED TO PANEL AND 110 OUTLET 
ON LOW VOLT TRIM PUT TV CONNECTORS ON THE ENDS AND LEAVE IN PANEL
SPLICE PHONE/CAT 5 TOGETHER MAKE SURE THE HOME RUN IS MARKED
IF WE DO CAT5 JACKS USE B PATTERN
ALL FLOURESCENT LAMPS IN RECESS AND FIXTURES 100% FLO’S 
USE ARLINGTON WEATHER PROOF BOXES 
WE DO NOT SUPPLY AIR SWITCHES FOR NTH 
2 WORK PLUGS AFTER ROUGH 
ON HOUSES WITH SPLIT DUCT SYSTEM PUT IN 50 AMP TEMP PLUG AND 30 AMP FOR TEMP HEAT 
RADON PLUG IN ATTIC OR CRAWL“
ELSE IF {?Builder}=’789123’
THEN
…
```

You get the picture.

Attached is a screenshot of how the code is being read in the formula. Is there any way to surpass this text as plain text so it is not read as code?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do what is known as escaping text.  When you escape something, you put a character or characters in front of commands in order to tell whatever is interpreting your code that it needs to treat whatever comes after the escape character differently than it usually does.  But maybe try this, where the big text block is now encapsulated with single quotes:

```
IF {?Builder}=”123456”
THEN
'QTXE FANS 6”  DUCT FOR ALL BATHROOMS WITH TUB OR SHOWER ' + ChrW(13) +
'QTRE FANS 4” DUCT ½ BATH OR ONLY ROOM AND THE LAUNDRY AS LONG AS IT IS NOT THE WHOLE HOUSE FAN ' + ChrW(13) +
"PULL WIRE FROM WHOLE HOUSE FAN SWITCH TO FURNACE "+ ChrW(13) +
"TERMINALS 4 & 6 on relay " + ChrW(13) +
"IF BIG CUSTOM VERIFY IF HOOD FAN NEEDS PULLED TO FURNACE "+ ChrW(13) +
"LOW VOLT PANEL WITH # 10 GROUND PULLED TO PANEL AND 110 OUTLET "+ ChrW(13) +
"ON LOW VOLT TRIM PUT TV CONNECTORS ON THE ENDS AND LEAVE IN PANEL "+ ChrW(13) +
"SPLICE PHONE/CAT 5 TOGETHER MAKE SURE THE HOME RUN IS MARKED "+ ChrW(13) +
"IF WE DO CAT5 JACKS USE B PATTERN "+ ChrW(13) +
"ALL FLOURESCENT LAMPS IN RECESS AND FIXTURES 100% FLO’S "+ ChrW(13) +
"USE ARLINGTON WEATHER PROOF BOXES "+ ChrW(13) +
"WE DO NOT SUPPLY AIR SWITCHES FOR NTH "+ ChrW(13) +
"2 WORK PLUGS AFTER ROUGH "+ ChrW(13) +
"ON HOUSES WITH SPLIT DUCT SYSTEM PUT IN 50 AMP TEMP PLUG AND 30 AMP FOR TEMP HEAT "+ ChrW(13) +
"RADON PLUG IN ATTIC OR CRAWL" ChrW(13) +
ELSE IF {?Builder}=’789123’
THEN
…
```

Comment: Hi, bf2020. Thanks for the response but that code didn't work. How would I implement "Escaping text"?

Comment: I updated the above code with Siva's answer, but the first two lines that have a double quote in the body of text are now encapsulated with single quotes.  The 1st single quote tells crystal that you want the stuff after it to be treated like text until it finds the next single quote.  Lines three through end are the same, except they use double quotes to tell crystal that everything betwixt is text.

Comment: The above edited code worked! Thanks so much @bf2020!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use reserved keyword as text for this do like this.

```
 Stringvar Array keys := ["\n"];
 Stringvar Array values := [Chr(10)+Chr(13)];
 text := Replace(text, keys[i], values[i])
```

[How to insert a line break in a StringVar in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177102/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-stringvar-in-crystal-reports)

[Double and single quote in string text in crystal report](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic453.html)

Answer (score 0):

Process you have followed is wrong.

1. If you want everything as a paragraph.

   ```
   IF {?Builder}=”123456”
   THEN
   “QTXE FANS 6”  DUCT FOR ALL BATHROOMS WITH TUB OR SHOWER "+
   "QTRE FANS 4” DUCT ½ BATH OR ONLY ROOM AND THE LAUNDRY AS LONG AS IT IS NOT THE WHOLE HOUSE FAN "+
   "PULL WIRE FROM WHOLE HOUSE FAN SWITCH TO FURNACE "+
   "TERMINALS 4 & 6 on relay "+
   "IF BIG CUSTOM VERIFY IF HOOD FAN NEEDS PULLED TO FURNACE "+
   "LOW VOLT PANEL WITH # 10 GROUND PULLED TO PANEL AND 110 OUTLET "+
   "ON LOW VOLT TRIM PUT TV CONNECTORS ON THE ENDS AND LEAVE IN PANEL "+
   "SPLICE PHONE/CAT 5 TOGETHER MAKE SURE THE HOME RUN IS MARKED "+
   "IF WE DO CAT5 JACKS USE B PATTERN "+
   "ALL FLOURESCENT LAMPS IN RECESS AND FIXTURES 100% FLO’S "+
   "USE ARLINGTON WEATHER PROOF BOXES "+
   "WE DO NOT SUPPLY AIR SWITCHES FOR NTH "+
   "2 WORK PLUGS AFTER ROUGH "+
   "ON HOUSES WITH SPLIT DUCT SYSTEM PUT IN 50 AMP TEMP PLUG AND 30 AMP FOR TEMP HEAT "+
   "RADON PLUG IN ATTIC OR CRAWL"
   ELSE IF {?Builder}=’789123’
   THEN
   …
   ```
2. If you want lines in separate line then follow below process:

   ```
   IF {?Builder}=”123456”
   THEN
   “QTXE FANS 6”  DUCT FOR ALL BATHROOMS WITH TUB OR SHOWER "+ ChrW(13) +
   "QTRE FANS 4” DUCT ½ BATH OR ONLY ROOM AND THE LAUNDRY AS LONG AS IT IS NOT THE WHOLE HOUSE FAN "+ ChrW(13) +
   "PULL WIRE FROM WHOLE HOUSE FAN SWITCH TO FURNACE "+ ChrW(13) +
   "TERMINALS 4 & 6 on relay "+ ChrW(13) +
   "IF BIG CUSTOM VERIFY IF HOOD FAN NEEDS PULLED TO FURNACE "+ ChrW(13) +
   "LOW VOLT PANEL WITH # 10 GROUND PULLED TO PANEL AND 110 OUTLET "+ ChrW(13) +
   "ON LOW VOLT TRIM PUT TV CONNECTORS ON THE ENDS AND LEAVE IN PANEL "+ ChrW(13) +
   "SPLICE PHONE/CAT 5 TOGETHER MAKE SURE THE HOME RUN IS MARKED "+ ChrW(13) +
   "IF WE DO CAT5 JACKS USE B PATTERN "+ ChrW(13) +
   "ALL FLOURESCENT LAMPS IN RECESS AND FIXTURES 100% FLO’S "+ ChrW(13) +
   "USE ARLINGTON WEATHER PROOF BOXES "+ ChrW(13) +
   "WE DO NOT SUPPLY AIR SWITCHES FOR NTH "+ ChrW(13) +
   "2 WORK PLUGS AFTER ROUGH "+ ChrW(13) +
   "ON HOUSES WITH SPLIT DUCT SYSTEM PUT IN 50 AMP TEMP PLUG AND 30 AMP FOR TEMP HEAT "+ ChrW(13) +
   "RADON PLUG IN ATTIC OR CRAWL" ChrW(13) +
   ELSE IF {?Builder}=’789123’
   THEN
   …
   ```

Comment: Hi Siva, thanks for the response. Your above code does not work. It says that a number, currency...etc. is required here regarding the first line after "THEN". However, bf2020's rendition of your code worked great. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You would be better served to embed each segment of text in its own `text object`, then show/suppress the text based on the parameter's value.

For example, the conditional-suppression logic for the `text object` that contains the example text would be:

```
{?Builder}<>"123456"
```

You could also put each `text object` in a separate section, then show/suppress the section using the same logic.